# How do I insert millions of records with speed and at once into an sql table using vb.net?

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, for-loop, bulkinsert

I have am filling gridview with data and insert record 1 by 1 into an sql table using a stored procedure which has only insert statement.

This is ok but when records are in millions then this takes a considerable time. I want to insert in speed into the table and should not take much time.

```
Try
        con.ConnectionString = v_ObjConn

        Dim ParamName(8), ParamType(8), ParamValue(8) As String

        ParamName(0) = "@WOCODE" : ParamType(0) = SqlDbType.VarChar
        ParamName(1) = "@WODESC" : ParamType(1) = SqlDbType.VarChar
        ParamName(2) = "@WOTYPE" : ParamType(2) = SqlDbType.VarChar
        ParamName(3) = "@TAGNUMBER" : ParamType(3) = SqlDbType.VarChar

        ParamName(4) = "@PMCODE" : ParamType(4) = SqlDbType.VarChar
        ParamName(5) = "@STATUS" : ParamType(5) = SqlDbType.VarChar
        ParamName(6) = "@COMPLETEDDATE" : ParamType(6) = SqlDbType.Date
        ParamName(7) = "@LASTUPDATE" : ParamType(7) = SqlDbType.Date

        lblWaitingMsg.Text = "Importing records into the VAIL-Plant. Please wait..."

        For Each row As GridViewRow In gv_InforWO.Rows

            Dim chkBoxSelect As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox)

            If chkBoxSelect.Checked = True Then

                ParamValue(0) = row.Cells(1).Text.ToString().Replace("&amp;", "and").Replace("&nbsp;", String.Empty)
                ParamValue(1) = row.Cells(2).Text.ToString().Replace("&amp;", "and").Replace("&nbsp;", String.Empty)
                ParamValue(2) = row.Cells(3).Text.ToString().Replace("&amp;", "and").Replace("&nbsp;", String.Empty)
                ParamValue(3) = row.Cells(4).Text.ToString().Replace("&amp;", "and").Replace("&nbsp;", String.Empty)

                ParamValue(4) = row.Cells(5).Text.ToString().Replace("&amp;", "and").Replace("&nbsp;", String.Empty)
                ParamValue(5) = row.Cells(6).Text.ToString().Replace("&amp;", "and").Replace("&nbsp;", String.Empty)
                ParamValue(6) = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells(7).Text)
                ParamValue(7) = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells(8).Text)

                Func.SP_ExecDML(con, "[dbo].[SP_InsertWorkOrders_InforEAM]", ParamName, ParamType, ParamValue)

            End If

        Next

        MsgBox("Records have been imported/updated.")

        BindGridInfoWO()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        lblWaitingMsg.Text = ""
    End Try
```

Comment: Use [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) instead of executing individual INSERT statements. Using a stored procedure won't make the INSERTs faster.

Comment: There's no way a user is going to display 1M rows in a grid though. Generating the HTML for all those rows is going to take a *lot* longer than actually inserting them. The user's browser won't be able to handle this either. What is the *real* data source for all those rows? If it's a flat file, why not use `BULK INSERT` in SQL to directly load the data?

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` in indeed the way to insert bulk data quickly but that generally involves data loaded from a file or another database or the like. As suggested, displaying that many records to the user is just madness. Where is the data coming from in the first place?

Comment: @jmcilhinney a web service. How do I divide it since it's sending once at all.

Comment: Does it even need to be displayed to the user?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes, because he has to select and import the desired records into the database.